# Kafka - Multiple Consumers From Same Group Assigned Same Partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have posted this over at the Kafka User mailing list but didn't get any responses so I figured I would try here as well.

I am currently attempting to upgrade my software to use Kafka 0.9 from 0.8.2. I am trying to
switch over to the new Consumer API to allow for rebalancing as machines are added or removed
from our cluster. I am running into an issue where the same partition on a topic is being
assigned to multiple consumers for a short period of time when a machine is added to the group.
This results in some of the messages being processed more than once, while I am aiming for
exactly once. I followed the setup instructions in the Javadocs and use an external data store
for saving the offsets while consuming and when rebalancing.

In my test cluster I start initially with 2 machines consuming and a single producer. Everything
works fine at the start and each consumer gets half of the partitions. When I add a third
machine it is assigned a portion of the partitions but these partitions aren't revoked from
one of the two initial machines. Below are some log statements from my program, hopefully
they help illustrate my situation.

Partition 14 is initially assigned to machine 1. Machine 1 reads a number of messages before
machine 3 is added. Partition 14 is assigned to machine 3 when started, but partition 14 was
not revoked from machine 1. Both machines then read the same message at offset 3 before the
system rebalances and both have access to partition 14 revoked. Machine 2 is then assigned
partition 14 after it is revoked from machine 1 but is still assigned to machine 3. After
it is revoked from machine 3, machine 2 is the only one with access to partition 14.

Machine 1 (Turned on at start)

```
2016-08-24 14:17:08 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:351 - ASSIGNED: Assigning partition 14 for topic
assignments to worker with offset 0
2016-08-24 14:18:48 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:312 - Committing topic assignments partition 14
offset 3
2016-08-24 14:19:38 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:200 - partition = 14, offset = 3 (Message read
from kafka)
2016-08-24 14:19:38 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:312 - Committing topic assignments partition 14
offset 4
2016-08-24 14:19:39 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:338 - REVOKED: Committing for partition 14 of
topic assignments offset 4
```

Machine 2 (Turned on at start)

```
2016-08-24 14:19:51 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:351 - ASSIGNED: Assigning partition 14 for topic
assignments to worker with offset 4
```

Machine 3 (Turned on a few minutes later)

```
2016-08-24 14:19:21 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:351 - ASSIGNED: Assigning partition 14 for topic
assignments to worker with offset 3
2016-08-24 14:19:48 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:200 - partition = 14, offset = 3 (Message read
from kafka - already read by machine 1)
2016-08-24 14:20:00 DEBUG KafkaStreamReader:338 - REVOKED: Committing for partition 14 of
topic assignments offset 4
```

My cluster is running Cloudera 5.7.0 with Kafka version 2.0.1-1.2.0.1.p0.5 which corresponds
to Kafka version 0.9.0.0+kafka2.0.1+283. (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_packaging.html)

Can anyone help explain what I'm doing wrong here? If there is any further information I can
provide to help this along please let me know and I will be happy to provide it if I can.

Comment: please check group-id of consumers. if possible update your consumer configuration for more details