# Kafka same partition is being assigned to consumers in same group

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

[Kafka - Multiple Consumers From Same Group Assigned Same Partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233763/kafka-multiple-consumers-from-same-group-assigned-same-partition)

I have just started learning Kafka and Nodejs. I have written a consumer as following

```
// consumer.js
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
var client = new kafka.Client('localhost:2181');
var topics = [{
    topic: 'topic-4'
}];

var options = {
    groupId: 'kafka-node-group-2',
    autoCommit: true,
    fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000,
    fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
    encoding: 'buffer'
};
var consumer = new kafka.HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options);

// consumer.payloads has only one entry
console.log('Topic', consumer.payloads[0].topic);
console.log('Group', consumer.options.groupId);
console.log('Assigned Partition:', consumer.payloads[0].partition);
```

Output

```
Topic topic-4
Group kafka-node-group-2
Assigned Partition: 0
```

`topic-4` has four partitions.

```
./desc_topic.sh topic-4
Topic:topic-4   PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: topic-4  Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: topic-4  Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
    Topic: topic-4  Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: topic-4  Partition: 3    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
```

**Edit**

I have used `ConsumerGroup` as follows.

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost:2181',  // zookeeper host omit if connecting directly to broker (see kafkaHost below)
    groupId: 'Group-1',
    sessionTimeout: 15000,
    // // An array of partition assignment protocols ordered by preference.
    // // 'roundrobin' or 'range' string for built ins (see below to pass in custom assignment protocol)
    protocol: ['roundrobin']
};
var consumer = new kafka.ConsumerGroup(options, ['topic-4']);
```

The producer is sending 100 messages that are received as the following. That's how I know the assigned partition (not from `consumer` object).

```
{
    topic: 'topic-4',
    value: '{"subject":"Message Id 30 "}',
    offset: 172,
    partition: 0,
    highWaterOffset: 173,
    key: null
}
```

When I run two such consumer instances (same topic and group), only one of them receives everything from partition-0. Isn't that a problem too?

This is the producer code.

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const Client = kafka.Client;
var client = new Client('localhost:2181', 'my-client-id', {
  sessionTimeout: 300,
  spinDelay: 100,
  retries: 2
});

// For this demo we just log client errors to the console.
client.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});

var producer = new kafka.HighLevelProducer(client);

producer.on('ready', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
        let id = 'Message Id ' + i + ' ';
        let msg = {
            'subject': id
        };
        var messageBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg));

        // Create a new payload
        var payload = [{
            // topic: 'topic-', + (i%2+2),
            topic: 'topic-4',
            messages: messageBuffer,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            attributes: 1 /* Use GZip compression for the payload */
        }];

        //Send payload to Kafka and log result/error
        producer.send(payload, function(error, result) {
            console.info('Sent payload to Kafka: ', payload);
            if (error) {
                console.error('Error', error);
            } else {
                var formattedResult = result[0];
                console.log('result: ', result)
            }
        });
    }
});

// For this demo we just log producer errors to the console.
producer.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: The problem looks fairly straightforward to me - remove the manual assignment of `partition: 0`

Comment: My bad! I did that for debugging purpos but the problem persists even without that. I have edited my question.

Comment: Have you tried using the ConsumerGroup class instead of HighLevelConsumer?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Same result.

Comment: Can you show your commands to create the topic and data insertion so someone could reproduce this issue?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Okay, well, looks like you've only sent data into partition 0 manually with `partition:0`, rather than let the message be appropriately partitioned in round robin since the key is null... But you're still not actually showing the real producer code. Anyways, also add the output of this command for the latest offsets of all partitions https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-GetOffsetShell

Comment: The partition in the json is the assigned one that is received at the consumer end. I am not passing that from the producer. I have added the producer code as well - not sure how that will help.

Comment: It helps because we can have a [mcve]. Keyword being verifiable, or able to be repeated outside of your specific case of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. I have encountered it as well. If you are using a more recent version of Kafka than posted for the fix, it may be worth re-examining and possibly re-opening this issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6681